# Gradle dependency error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx, appwarp

I am using `Gradle 2.4` and `Android Studio 1.3`. I have tried to use `AppWarp`'s `JAR` file as a dependency in a `libGDX` project. I have got following error during `Gradle` sync:

```
Gradle DSL method not found 'compile()'
```

I put code below in `allprojects` section.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/App42MultiPlayerGamingSDK.jar')
}
```

Comment: what type of dependency you are trying to add in gradle?

Comment: include it in `build.gradle(module.app)`

Comment: are you sure, you need it for `allprojects`, but not in the `app` project? Try to add this dependency into app's build.gradle script.

Comment: I see these Gradle files: http://prntscr.com/929nrg There is no `app` project.

Comment: @MZubairShamshad : This is not a default android project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppWarpMultiPlayerGamingSDK` should be added to Android Studio as a module in the core project, by right click on project.

> Select Module Setting
>
> And SDK as a module library.

Thanks to AppWarp Support Team!

Answer (score 0):

You can't put "`compile`" in the `allprojects` section because that section does not have the `java` plugin applied, and therefore can only accept classpath dependencies. You could put `apply plugin: "java"` at the top of the `allprojects` block, but that will only lead you to the next problem...

Isn't that jar an Android-based library anyway? It will cause your other modules to fail to compile if you put it in `allprojects`. It needs to go in the `android` section's dependencies.

Comment: Okay, but in this case how can it work in desktop project. It is a multi platform framework.

Comment: There should be a separate library for each supported platform. Download the various libraries and assign them to their respective platforms in your Gradle file. And you will need to create an interface in the core project that the Desktop, Android, etc. projects use to adapt the library for use in core. Read here: http://saltares.com/blog/games/abstracting-platform-specific-code-in-libgdx/

Comment: That is okay, but how can I make this in Gradle script files?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: These are specified in Gradle files, not in Java files. So I cannot use interfaces in Gradle script files.

Comment: Read that link I put above. No one said anything about putting an interface in the Gradle file.

Comment: That is okay, but if I put this dependency in android section it cannot be used in desktop program.

Comment: It can't be used by the desktop project anyway because it's an Android library. That's why I said you need to download a separate desktop library for desktop.

Comment: Please see my project files here: https://github.com/kovacsa91/superjumper Can you please make a pull reuest for that file maybe?

Comment: Sorry, can't invest the time to learn their API and do that. I honestly don't know how to explain it any clearer than above and what's in that linked article.

Comment: I know interfaces and how to use platform specific code on another platform, but Gradle's method seems different. I only would like to now, exactly how to integrate jar into Gradle script.

Comment: Gradle sync is now successful, but imports are undefined.